# Play framework JPA query nested object not available

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have three objects that are related to eachother.

```
@Entity
class Club extends Model

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "club")
   public Set<Car> cars;

@Entity
class Car extends Model

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   public Club club;

@Entity
class Booking extends Model

   public Date startTime;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   public Car car;

   public static Collection<Booking> bookingsForClubInPeriod(Club club, Date start, Date end){
      return Booking.find("startTime > ? and startTime < ? and car.club = ?", start, end, club).fetch();
   }
```

I can search for Bookings that start between two times, but when I add car.club to the query, I get zero results.

I also tried changing the query to:
     find("startTime > ? and startTime < ? and car in ?", start, end, club.cars) but with no luck (that gave me this message: *Could not get a field value by reflection getter of models.Car.id*

Another try was to add FetchType.EAGER to both cars and club, but that didn't help either.

Also if I do a find on Car I can get the club, and the other way around. It's just in this query I can't find it.
The model objects are simplified, but should provide enough information to explain my problem.

Any Ideas why I can't query based on the nested object club?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the "magic" Play! adds to partial queries but this Hibernate query should work

```
select b from Booking b left join b.car car left join car.club club where b.startTime > :startTime and b.endTime < :endTime and club = :club
```

Note that we use a left (outer) join which means that even if the car is not there, we should get results

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. The query does unfortunately give me the exact same result.

Comment: Sorry for posting this. My query works perfectly fine, it was just me not looking hard enough at my unit tests. Found an error on the creation of Car that gave it a different name than I expected.

I guess the solution suggested above by Emmanuel also works.